# Convert rows of data into table similar to pivot but with actual values

Tags: mysql, excel, pivot-table

I have data in a mysql table in the format

```
C1 | C2 | C3 (Column titles)  
A1 | X1 | Y1  
A1 | X2 | Y2  
A1 | X3 | Y3  
B1 | X1 | Y4  
B1 | X2 | Y5  
B1 | X3 | Y6  
B1 | X4 | Y7  
C1 | X1 | Y8  
C1 | X2 | Y9
```

I'd like to convert this to

```
00 | X1 | X2 | X3 | X4  
A1 | Y1 | Y2 | Y3 |   
B1 | Y4 | Y5 | Y6 | Y7  
C1 | Y8 | Y9
```

Much like a pivot table but putting the actual values of Yx in the table rather than performing an operation (Sum / Avg etc.) on them.

Is there an easy way to do this in mysql or excel/libreoffice?

Thanks

Comment: Are the distinct values in C2 is X1, ..., X4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SQLFiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a59b98/4)

```
select 
C1,
max(case when c2='X1' then C3 else '' end) as `X1`,
max(case when c2='X2' then C3 else '' end) as `X2`,
max(case when c2='X3' then C3 else '' end) as `X3`,
max(case when c2='X4' then C3 else '' end) as `X4`

from t
group by C1
```